# Автоматическое направление взгляда яндекс панорам на объект

Tags: yandex-maps-api, панорамы

Имеются координаты дома, хочу открыть панорамы с видом на этот дом. Направление взгляда по умолчанию всегда на север. Как установить направление по умолчанию на дом?

Открывают панорамы так:

```js
panoramaManager.openPlayer([lat, lon])
```

upd: решение

```js
panoramaManager.getPlayer().lookAt([lat, lon])
```

Comment: В документации есть третий параметр https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/panorama.Manager.html#method_detail__openPlayer

Comment: @AlexeyTen, по документации туда нужно передавать конкретные значения (угол поворота), которые нельзя знать на момент открытия панорам

Comment: нашел метод [lookAt](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/panoramas/panorama-manage.html#panorama-functions) которую можно вызвать после открытия панорам `panoramaManager.getPlayer().lookAt([lat, lon])`, в принципе проблема решена